# Walking along a path of names to get a deep value from a Node

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I am in the process of porting a PHP console app to C++, to learn more about C++ and reignite my old love for the language.

One of the things I need is traversing through a parsed YAML tree, to get an item by it's path. I am currently only handling string keys and YAML map types, just to keep it simple.

Here's the test I wrote using [Catch](http://catchlib.net) to identify my  issue:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include "include/catch.hpp"

// In my actual implementation, this function is a method 
// of a class, and 'config' is a class member
// but the semantics and types are the same
YAML::Node lookup(YAML::Node config, std::vector<std::string>& path) {
    YAML::Node ptr = config;

    BOOST_FOREACH(std::string element, path)
    {
        ptr = ptr[element];
    }

    return ptr;
}


TEST_CASE ("Loading YAML data", "[loader]") {
    const char *str_config =
        "key:\n"
        "    child: Hello world\n"
    ;
    YAML::Node config = YAML::Load(str_config);

    std::vector<std::string> path;

    path.push_back("key");
    path.push_back("child");

    // the first one succeeds:
    REQUIRE( lookup(config, path).IsDefined() );

    // but the second one fails.
    REQUIRE( lookup(config, path).IsDefined() );
}
```

Now if I run this test, it fails with the following message:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading YAML data
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/gerard/work/z-cpp/test.cpp:26
...............................................................................

/home/gerard/work/z-cpp/test.cpp:42: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( lookup(config, path).IsDefined() )
with expansion:
  false

===============================================================================
test cases: 1 | 1 failed
assertions: 2 | 1 passed | 1 failed
```

I have isolated that if I clone the node in the lookup method like this:

```
YAML::Node ptr = YAML::Clone(config);
```

it works just fine.

### What it does

Somehow, the internal state of the 'config' object is altered. But since I declare my local variable not as a reference, I expected it to make a copy of the original. I started out using just references, with which I ran into the same issue.

Also, if the vector is initialized separately a second time with another instance, it acts the same (erroneous) way, so it's not the vector's fault ;)

I have dived a bit into the source code of yaml-cpp and tried to figure out if I am missing some obvious pointers (pun intended) or API misuse, but I can't figure it out...

### What it should do

As my 'lookup' is just a read operation, I would like to have as much things `const` as possible, and not have the original object's state altered. Also, cloning the entire tree will make it very expensive as I plan to do a lot of these lookups in the entire application...

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yaml-cpp, nodes are reference types, so `operator=` actually changes their internals.

This often is what you want, but your example shows that in some cases it produces really counterintuitive behavior.

I agree this is weird. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/208) to think about how to prevent this in intuitive behavior.

To work around this, in your example, you could switch to recursion:

```
template <typename Iter>
YAML::Node lookup(YAML::Node node, Iter start, Iter end) {
  if (start == end) {
    return node;
  }
  return lookup(node[*start], next(start), end);
}

...

vector<string> path = ...
YAML::Node value = lookup(config, path.begin(), path.end());
```

Comment: Ah, I get the issue now :) Thanks for the alternative implementation as well :) I tried fiddling around with pointers to work around this, but I couldn't get it to work either.